# Feature selection for SVM and Maximum Entropy

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, feature-selection, maximum-entropy

In text classification problems where the number of features >> number of documents, is it useful to perform feature selection with filters (e.g. Information Gain) when using Naive Bayes. However, what about SVM and Maximum Entropy classifiers ?

Comment: would PCA do what you need?